# Dependent variables for logistic regression

Tags: r, model, regression

I am having a mental blank and need some help with a final part of my study. To summarize:

I have a population of cats, they have been scored as either obese/overweight (1) or not obese/overweight (O) using two different methods - a visual scoring method and a verbal scoring method. I obtained results that approx 30% were scored as 1 using the visual scale, 32% scored as 1 using the verbal scale, and 23% scored as 1 using both scales.

I have completed univariable and multivariable log regression using both the visual and verbal scores as dependent variables. I now want to do a third model using a score of 1 on both scales as the dependent variable.

How do I go ahead and do this using R? I feel that it's something quite simple that I have just forgotten.

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. I can't tell if you are asking for a statistical method or an R function. A reproducible example might help.

Comment: Hi, I understand about including an example but I wasn't sure how to do that in this case. I could post the code from my two multivariate analyses if that would be helpful? I guess it is both the statistical method and then the r code that I don't know!

Comment: Yes, it seems like it would be easiest to create a new column with either score of 1 on both scales, or 0. How can I do that using R?

Comment: @eipi10 why would you use `ifelse`to do that? Just use the logical expression you pass as `test` to `ifelse`. `ifelse` is for when you want to assign some meaning beyond true or false to a logical test, i.e., male or female.  If you're assigning 1s  and 0s, just use the logical expression.